# Python : read a data set file

Tags: python, database, file

I have to read and store a data file composed of 3 columns and N row *Number of block .. here a simple example:

```
z=3 
1 2 3 
2 5 6 
1 5 7

z=2
1 3 9
2 5 7
```

which is the best way to read this file and store several block of z row using python ?

**EDIT**: I have to store them into a separate blocks (indexed) for example in the above example I should have

```
block[0]=[[1 2 3],[2 5 6],[1 5 7]] 
block[1] = [[1 3 9],[2 57]]
```

@shahaf e come lo indicizzo ? scusa ma sono un noob in python :)
could some body explain me how to indicize the several blocks ? and in particular I wrote `z= N` but in reality it's

```
 ZONE I=     41  F=POINT  TIME T=      0.0000715363
```

I have to catch 41 .. and read and store the follow 41 line, than after a couple of white line I encounter another `ZONE` section .. I don't know how many zone I there are in the file ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple draft of the solution, it can be simplified, but you can take it from here

```
tmp_arr= list()
output=list()
with open('file.txt') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
      pass
    elif line.startswith('z='):
      counter = int(line.split('=')[-1])
    else:
      tmp_arr.append(line.split())
      counter -= 1
      if counter == 0:
        output.append(tmp_arr)
        tmp_arr = list()
```

output

```
[[['1', '2', '3'], ['2', '5', '6'], ['1', '5', '7']], [['1', '3', '9'], ['2', '5', '7']]]
```

Comment: Apparently i don't have permission to edit your answer. Anyways, your code doesn't compile for noobs since you need to change your 2nd last line to `output.append(tmp_arr)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how exactly you want to store them, but a quick generic way to do it I found with the regex module and a for loop:

```
import re

with open('path/to/file', 'r') as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

# Should give this structure
# lines = ['z=3','1 2 3', '4 5 6', '7 8 9', 'z=2', '3 5 9', '8 6 4', 'z=5', '12 3 5', '8 5 7', '1 1 1', '2 3 2', '6 6 5']

blocks = []

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if 'z=' in lines[i]:
        j = re.findall('\d',lines[i])[0]
        block = lines[i+1:i+j]
        blocks.append(block)
    else:
        continue
```

`blocks` will wind up having a list-of-lists structure: `[['1 2 3', '4 5 6', ...], [...]]`. You can further refine it by using the `split()` method, but this should get you off the ground. Granted, this does assume you can get your data into the structure at the start, which is easy if it's in a file, but I'm not sure if you are pulling from a database or not